# выпадающий список в выпадающем списке

Tags: css

Добрый день Всем , подскажите пожалуйста как организовать так выпадающий список что б по нажатию на "категория" последний элемент на первой картинке(левой) уходил стягивался в низ и после того как если закрыть елемент "категория" он обратно стягивался

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это называется аккордеон...примеров в инете больше, чем людей на планете http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse..... http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/accordion-menu ....http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h  ....http://itchief.ru/lessons/bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3-accordion https://jqueryui.com/accordion/   ....http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Bootstrap-Style-Vertical-Accordion-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3-bs-leftnavi/ -> http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Bootstrap-Style-Vertical-Accordion-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3-bs-leftnavi.html

Comment: мультилевел на чистом css https://codyhouse.co/demo/multi-level-accordion-menu/index.html там есть ссылка на доки, вот еще красивое http://webpulse.com.br/jquery-accordion-menu/demo.html